# Check boxes for showing categories

Tags: categories

Is there a way to list all categories with check boxes on side bar and when user presses "update" only posts within those categories will show on home page?

Answer (score 1):

Although it looks like by default it has the categories as a dropdown select, it looks like this plugin could be slightly modified to fit your needs:

[Taxonomy Picker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-picker/)

> Taxonomy Picker is a widget which you can include in your sidebar to
>   help visitors build complex queries using categories and your custom
>   taxonomies by chosing terms from drop down boxes.

Comment: Thanks Gavin-this just what I was looking for in a widget.
Is it possible to tweak the code on the small black boxes to something more visually pleasing?
I can most likely change the code, but didn't know if it was something one should avoid.

Comment: Great, I did use it but am needing some changes to work for me.